# Firestore search array contains for more than one document

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Cloud Firestore and I want to use more than one "whereArrayContains". I know it is not possible, but is there another solution for it?

This is a screenshot of the DB:

[image]

The user put in his postal code (here: plz) and the app looks for the document. Then the user can choose a sport.
For example: plz: 50001 and sport: soccer
How do I search for it?

I know it doesn't work this way:

```
colRef = db.collection("Sponsoren");

colRef.whereArrayContains("plz", "50001")
    .whereArrayContains("sport", "soccer")
```

In the next step, there is a search for the age group, so I have to search for three values in three different arrays.
For example: plz: 50001 and sport: soccer and age: adult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution to solving this problem would be to change the type of those fields from `array` to `map`. So your database schema might look like this:

```
db
|
--- products (collection)
     |
     --- $productId (document)
           |
           --- plz (map)
           |   |
           |   --- 50000: true
           |   |
           |   --- 50001: true
           |
           --- sport (map)
           |   |
           |   --- soccer: true
           |   |
           |   --- jackets: true
           |
           --- age (map)
               |
               --- youth: true
               |
               --- adult: true
```

Now to get all products where the `plz` holds the value of `50001` and the `sport` is `soccer` and the `age` is `adult`, then you have to use the following query:

```
Query query = db.collection("products")
                .whereEqualTo("plz.50001", true)
                .whereEqualTo("sport.soccer", true)
                .whereEqualTo("age.adult", true);
```

Comment: I am not finished yet, but I think that will work for me.  Thank you very much!